# Multiple Column Structure Java

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

In C# there is DataTable type which can be used to create multi-column structures. In java I can use nested hashmaps but its too complicated structure even if you have 3 columns. Does core java support any such structure without including any external library?

I can use multidimensional arrays but still checking for any possible option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java has no directly available table format. However, we can use the generics functionality to our advantage here. You can read about them [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). Instantiation will look like this

```
Map<String, List<String>> tableMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Now, you have a 2D structure with an identifier String for every row, and the rest of the row stored as a list. You do need to choose unique identifiers for each row though, so if you are aiming to map it with a table (as you do in C#), make sure that the key of the HashMap is the primary key of the table.

I hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bi-dimensional [`Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Table.html) in [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), but nothing in the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent in Java. You can use `javax.sql.rowset.WebRowSet` or `java.sql.ResultSet` to build data structure.